# TableAdapter occasionally returning row count 1 but all null columns

Tags: c#, .net, sql, tableadapter

I'll hit refresh on my page 20 times and it will work, then a few minutes later it stops working for 5min. The tableadapter says that it has a count of 1 but when i access a property eg : tableadapter1[0].property1 it throws an exception:

[StrongTypingException: The value for column 'blogpull_keywords' in table 'blogpull' is DBNull.]

but when i run the Stored proc behind that method in SQL Management it doesn't return any nulls just data.

```
careers.jobdepartmentDataTable dtDepartments = new jobdepartmentTableAdapter().GetDepartmentByJobID(iJobID);
        if (dtDepartments.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                iDepartmentID = dtDepartments[0].job_department_id; //thows error here
            }
            catch
            {
                Context.Response.Write("error info: " + iJobID.ToString());
                Context.Response.End();
            } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set MultipleActiveResultSets = true in the connection string and this error went away.